# Windows Server 2012 - Domain Admin: Can't change printer ports

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I'm a domain admin of my network and some of the printer settings don't allow me to change. I'd have to logon to the local admin to be able to change printer settings. Can this be enabled for domain admins?

[image]

Comment: Under Control Panel > Devices and Printers did you select 'Print Server Properties'? See http://blacktheman.blogspot.com/2011/11/access-denied-message-when-changing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Control Panel > Devices and Printers select 'Print Server Properties'

[image]

More information - http://blacktheman.blogspot.com/2011/11/access-denied-message-when-changing.html